# Change the date format using Carbon - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a date in my database which is 2018-05-21 00:00:00.00000
I would like to get the name of the month , I am trying to make the date as a carbon format (not sure if it is not) with this code

```
    `$timestemp = Carbon::create('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp)->toFormattedDateString();`
```

and I am getting this error

`Unexpected data found.
Trailing data`

If anyone have an alternative solution or know a fix for the issue please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the name of month try using below code

```
$timestemp = Carbon::parse($timestamp)->format('F');
```